# Creating a list that can hold multiple values per entry

Tags: lists, etoolbox

I wand to create a list which can hold different values per entry.
As an example I want to list users and every user has a Username, Age and Country.
Now I want to be able to iterate through the list and getting the three values Username, Age and Country so that I can print this list:

```
Anna|27|England
Bob|35|Italy
```

for example like this:

```
The user Anna is 27 and comes from England.
The user Bob is 35 and comes from Italy.
```

Is there a nice solution?
I already tried the package etoolbox, but I couldn't fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [`LaTeX3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) provides token lists or comma separated lists or property lists …

Comment: Are you asking for a database approach? That would be a natural solution to your description.

Comment: No, not a database approach. At the end I want to use it for a own package or class that I can include in all my latex projects. Its many meant to store data about all authors since the latex projects are often group projects. One author needs to contain the name, email, curs of study and some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document} 
\setsepchar[,]{\\,/}
\readlist*\mylist{
Anna/27/England\\
Bob/35/Italy 
}

\foreachitem\z\in\mylist[]{%
  The user \mylist[\zcnt,1] is \mylist[\zcnt,2] and comes
  from \mylist[\zcnt,3].\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I show the approach where data are accumulated in the `\list` macro first and then the `\printlist` iterates over this `\list`. Only TeX primitives are used:

```
\def\printlist#1{\expandafter\printlistA#1{}}
\def\printlistA#1{\ifx\relax#1\relax \else 
   \printitem#1\end \expandafter\printlistA\fi}

\def\list{{Anna|27|England}{Bob|35|Italy}}
\def\printitem #1|#2|#3\end{The user #1 is #2 and comes from #3.\par}

\printlist\list
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that comment. It works :D If that's no big deal I'd like to get a little explanation. Then I would be able to use it more flexible for example by defining a second output sentence.

Comment: Or is there a Latex solution, since I'm already struggling with that.
I'd prefer to not touch tex primitives :(

Comment: @Krypton If you know behavior of TeX primitives then you can do anything. You need not to know more. LaTeX does things more complicated. For example, we have `\def` (and three logical alternatives) but LaTeX have `\newcommand`, `\NewDocumentCommand`, Expl3 `\tl_set:Nn`, `\cs_new:Nn` and many more. Ones head spins. Moreover, when you avoid LaTeX macros then your solution works in any TeX format. TeX syntax is (for example) `\hsize=13cm`, LaTeX provides macro `\setlength{\hsize}{13cm}` etc. You can read how TeX works: http://petr.olsak.net/ftp/olsak/optex/tex-nutshell.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\user}[3]{The user {#1} is {#2} years old and come from {#3}.}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \user{Ann}{27}{England}\\
    \user{Bob}{35}{Italy}
\end{document}
```

can help? It produce this output:

[image]

If You have a long list, You can store the data ina a *.text file and read the file from the `LaTeX` code.

Comment: The \newcommand command doesn't help a lot, since I need to print the information at different positions in different styles.

But the possibility to read in a file is a nice hint. 
Still no clue how to do that but I'll find a way! 

Thanks :D